# Remove duplicates in an array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects which is similar to:

```
Questions-answers  [{"questions":"Q_18002_Error_message","answers":"Yes"},{"questions":"Q_18002_Error_message","answers":"No"},{"questions":"Q_18001","answers":"No"}]
```

I want to delete `{"questions":"Q_18002_Error_message","answers":"Yes"}` because I have a new updated answer to the question Q_18002,
I am a newbie in Javascript and I am stuck on how to delete the duplicate elements but based on the questions only and delete the old ones and leave the new objects. I hope that I made it clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may build up the [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/Map) (with [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)) using `questions` as a key, overwriting previously seen values, then extract array of unique records  with [`Map.prototype.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values):

```js
const src = [{"questions":"Q_18002_Error_message","answers":"Yes"},{"questions":"Q_18002_Error_message","answers":"No"},{"questions":"Q_18001","answers":"No"}],
 
      result = [...src
        .reduce((r,o) => (r.set(o.questions,o), r), new Map)
        .values()
      ]
      
console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Comment: Can you please explain these lines for me if it is possible? what was the use of the points next to src ?

Comment: @Houdakilani : `Map.prototype.values()` returns iterator object, so those 3 dots inside square brackets ([spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)) are used to actually iterate `Map` values and put those into array. If anything else confuses you, feel free to ask.